# Карточка Html, Css

Tags: html, css

Как верстать для мобильных и пк
введите сюда описание изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если что то не ясно спрашивайте

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.cart {
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/35845/pub_5df5edfdc31e4900ba3d49e5_5df5ee1c78125e00ae85c254/scale_1200);
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.cart:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.cart h3 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #3fbffb;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.cart_outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.cart_outer-btns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cart_outer-offert p {
  padding-left: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 16px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.cart_outer-offert p i.fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .cart {
    width: 320px;
  }
  .cart h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .btn {
    padding: 3px 4px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
  }
  .cart_outer-offert p {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="parent">

  <div class="cart">
    <h3>Обзорная экскурсия по <br> Одессе</h3>
    <div class="cart_outer">

      <div class="cart_outer-offert">
        <p><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Пешеходная экскурсия</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 8 часов</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> 1000 грн</p>
      </div>

      <div class="cart_outer-btns">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Групповая</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Индивидуальная</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cart">
    <h3>Обзорная экскурсия по <br> Одессе</h3>
    <div class="cart_outer">

      <div class="cart_outer-offert">
        <p><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Пешеходная экскурсия</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 8 часов</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> 1000 грн</p>
      </div>

      <div class="cart_outer-btns">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Групповая</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Индивидуальная</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cart">
    <h3>Обзорная экскурсия по <br> Одессе</h3>
    <div class="cart_outer">

      <div class="cart_outer-offert">
        <p><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Пешеходная экскурсия</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 8 часов</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> 1000 грн</p>
      </div>

      <div class="cart_outer-btns">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Групповая</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Индивидуальная</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```